# Issue with whitespace between text in a web page

Tags: c#, regex, html

I trying to remove white space between text using Regex. Below input string is rendered on a web page.

```
string inputString = "あさ9：30 - よる10：00";
Regex Spaces = new Regex(@"\s+");
string s = Spaces.Replace(inputString, string.Empty);
```

The Regex pattern is not working on the inputstring. The space between 9: 30 and 10: 00 doesn't look like a white space. Not sure what kind of space it is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you are saying that after you run the regex the string looks like the following "あさ9：30-よる10：00" With no space on either side of the dash "-"

Comment: what is the exact output you want?

Answer (score 3):

Your character `：` is not what you think it is. Look *very closely*. You think it is : when it is actually ： Those are two different characters. Also, there is *no whitespace there at all*.

Seriously: The character is not a standard colon. It is a different character. Look at the two side-by-side here:

：:

Comment: Right, it's u+ff1a, a "fullwidth colon."

Comment: I wonder if it is some fancy unicode stuff like many-in-one glyphs and whether it could be normalized/decomposed or it is an atomic thing.

Comment: It's nothing fancy, just a weird colon with a bunch of space around it.

Comment: @GGG Right... which is what is causing the user to think there is 'whitespace' there.

Comment: It's Japanese language web page. I am using UTF8 encoding to get the content from web page. Encoding might have converted it this way. My guess.

Comment: @Naveen Those fullwidth characters are for doing monospace-like things with non-monospace fonts, I think. They are in the same order as the non-fullwitdh characters, so you can subtract a fixed value from the character code to get the corresponding non-fullwidth character.

Comment: More about that, including list of what's in fullwidth unicode range: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to do just a simple `replace(" ","")`?  That normally works for me when regex doesn't work.

Comment: Same thing, "：" is a character.

Comment: @Rab So it's not whitespace and can't be removed as such.

Comment: @Rab Nawaz So, simple replace("：",":"); though this does not look very generic.

Comment: @Rab **NO**. It is *not* `: `. It is `：` That's a totally different character than `:` and *there is no whitespace there at all*

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev is correct. It is a character. I had to use another regex to replace

string inputString = "あさ9：30 - よる10：00";
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[：]", ":");